# Angular Unit test - testing a status with http POST request

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have this function in my ts file

```
public submit(model) {
  const data: TestModel = new TestModel();
  data.name = 'John Doe';
  data.age = '25';
  this.currentStatus = 'SUBMITTING';
  this.userService.submitUser(data).subscribe({
    next: () => (this.currentStatus = 'DONE'),
    error: () => (this.currentStatus = 'FAILED'),
  });
}
```

Now, I'm trying to test the request status when it's SUBMITTING or if it's DONE or FAILED

```
it('The status should be SUBMITTING and then change to DONE if the request succeeded', () => {
  const MOCK_DETAILS = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: '25'
  };
  spyOn<any>(component as any, 'submit');
  expect(component.currentStatus).toEqual('SUBMITTING')
  component.submit(MOCK_DETAILS);
  expect(component.currentStatus).toEqual('DONE')
});
```

It seems like the currentStatus always having the initial value. Is there a good approach to test the status and follow it during the http request?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your test you are expecting that the status is 'SUBMITTING' before actually calling the submit function. So the value of your status is never changed to 'SUBMITTING'. I would test this function in two seperate test cases testing for FAILED and DONE. Something like this:

```
it('submit function returning DONE', () => {
  const MOCK_DETAILS = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: '25'
  };
  const mockResponseData = {
   .....
  };
  spyOn(userService, 'submitUser').and.returnValue(of(mockResponseData))
  component.submit(MOCK_DETAILS);
  expect(userService.submitUser).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(component.currentStatus).toBe('DONE')
});

it('submit function returning FAILED', () => {
  const MOCK_ERROR = {
   // Object causing the function to throw error
  };
  const mockResponseData = {
   .....
  };
  spyOn(userService, 'submitUser').and.returnValue(of(mockResponseData))
  component.submit(MOCK_ERROR);
  expect(userService.submitUser).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(component.currentStatus).toBe('FAILED')
});
```

In order to test the implementation of the userService.submitUser method I would write the tests in a seperate file like a userSerivice.spec.ts file.

IMHO I think you can omit the 'SUBMITTING' status and only check for FAILED and DONE as the serviceCall should succeed.